# Conditional statement in selenium if element does not exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to check

> def first_page_error:
>
> -if the element is not existing "break" and move on with the script
>
> -if element exists then refresh the page
>
> -if element stops existing after the refresh run firstPage()

I will appreciate any help I'm learning python :)

My code right now

```
def first_page_error():
        cap_error = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js-register-with-email"]/div[2]')
        while True:
            try:
                cap_error
            except NoSuchElementException:
                break
            else:
                time.sleep(5)
                driver.refresh()

    def firstPage():
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sign-up-link"]')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

        emailInput = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="register-email"]')
        emailInput.send_keys(emails[0])

        condInput = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="register-terms"]')
        condInput.click()

    firstPage()
    first_page_error()
```

Comment: and what isn't working with your code? Is this using a public url?

Comment: The problem is that if the element is not present the if statement keeps refreshing the page

Comment: Could you please make the indents of your code consistent and correct. Also, in code you firstly run `firstPage()`, then `first_page_error()`. You are asking "-if element stops existing after the refresh run firstPage()". Should there be second call of `firstPage()`?

Answer (score 2):

A few points of feedback...

1. If you are automating user scenarios, avoid using JS clicks. A user can't click an element that isn't visible or is covered or is off the screen, etc. Selenium was designed to act like a user and throw errors when a user can't click an element. That's a good thing. It helps you find the problems and solve them as a user would.
2. Prefer IDs and CSS selectors. They are faster, better supported, and so on. There's a lot of info on the web if you want more explanation. I converted your XPaths that were just locating by ID to *_by_id().
3. Check for existence by using driver.find_elements_* (Notice the plural, elementS) and check the len of the collection

I would write something like the below.

```
def first_page_error():
    return len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="js-register-with-email"]/div[2]')) > 0

def firstPage():
    driver.find_element_by_id('sign-up-link').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('register-email').send_keys(emails[0])
    driver.find_element_by_id('register-terms').click()

firstPage()
if first_page_error():
    driver.refresh()
    if first_page_error():
        firstPage()
# move on with the script
```

Comment: if first_page_error()
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: did exactly like you've told

Comment: Thanks for the advice I have changed the whole script to id

Comment: I did not understand why did you call the ```first_page_error``` again inside the condition? If you do not get the element in the 2nd condition, the ```firstPage()``` will be called any which ways

Comment: @LibinThomas I honestly don't remember... it's been too long. Looking at it again today, I don't understand why I checked `first_page_error()` again. It seems like the second `if` should be removed but there's other issues as well like you can get into an infinite loop because there's no escape, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for input 
I've resolved it with this

```
def err_redeem_func():
    err_redeem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('error')
    try:
        if err_redeem.is_displayed() and err_redeem.is_enabled():
            driver.refresh()
            redeem_func()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass


err_redeem_func()
```

Comment: But if driver couldn't locate the element in your second line then it will be another error